# Does Intel 320 SSD require TRIM?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, trim

My computer does not recognize Intel 320 SSD drive as SSD (Intel utility does not allow to TRIM it or read SMART data from it), but I can install and use it like any other drive.

I've read that some SSD drives don't require TRIM to maintain performance and longevity as much as others because they have some internal cleaning.
Can Intel 320 SSD be safely used without TRIM ?
Safely I mean without significant loss of performance and longevity.

Comment: No SSD *requires* TRIM, it is a nice to have, and can even introduce risk. There is some performance benefit, but if your writes are sufficiently buffered you should not notice. Especially if the interface is slow. You can always zero unused space manually, including cluster tips, from a scheduled job during off peak times..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A user [reviewing the Intel 320](http://www.anandtech.com/show/4244/intel-ssd-320-review/11) SSD claims the following:

> The 320 behaves a lot like the old X25-M G2 did when tortured. Minimum
>   performance drops pretty low - Intel prefers cleaning up as late as
>   possible to extend drive longevity. As a result, I wouldn't recommend
>   using the 320 in an OS without TRIM support.

You can see the difference in the graphs:

**Before:**

[image]

**After TRIM:**

[image]